# How to count binary length in O(1)?

Tags: c++, performance, binary, big-o, bit

Normally, I have to convert an integer to binary in a std::string then use the method std::string::size() to get the length of the binary number.

So **100** gives "**1100100**" (the length is **7**)

But it is a O(n) algorithm (at least), and I am writing a performance-intensive program that requires lots of bit counting. Is there any algorithm that lets we know the length of any given 'binary' number without having to convert the number to std::string beforehand in an instant? Thanks.

Comment: `O(1)` or `O(log(N))`?

Comment: You can use `ceil(log2(100))` to get `7`. The problem is I don't know what the complexity to calculate `log2` is.

Comment: Here is my O(n) algorithm. It might be not O(n), but completely not O(1).
int32_t countBinaryLength(int32_t n)
{
    std::string r;
    do 
 {
  r = (n % 2 == 0 ? "0" : "1") + r;
  n /= 2;
 } while(n != 0);

    return r.size();
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are computing a binary logarithm. There are a number of ways to do it, described on the [bit twiddling hacks page](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogIEEE64Float).

One simple approach uses a look-up table. First, make a look-up table at start-up:

```
LogTable256[0] = LogTable256[1] = 0;
for (int i = 2; i != 256; i++) {
    LogTable256[i] = 1 + LogTable256[i / 2];
}
LogTable256[0] = -1; // if you want log(0) to return -1
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```
if (tt = v >> 24) {
    r = 24 + LogTable256[tt];
} else if (tt = v >> 16) {
    r = 16 + LogTable256[tt];
} else if (tt = v >> 8) {
    r = 8 + LogTable256[tt];
} else {
    r = LogTable256[v];
}
```

Comment: This will work for a finite N, isn't it? In this case 32 bit?

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, this one is limited to 32 bits. One can expand this to 64 bits by doing "more of the same".

Comment: Yes, I was thinking more about an arbitrary precision number. In that case I don't think there's any `O(1)` algorithm. Although I'm pretty sure OP deals with fixed-sized numbers here so good answer!

Comment: I have tried it, but your method returns 6. What is wrong?

Comment: Since OP is looking for the length of the string, the initial values for `LogTable256` should be 1, not 0.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my one liner answer, but it depends on how `log2()` is implemented in your machine.

```
length = ceil(log2(number))
```

Comment: if number is 2, then this returns 1, while the length is actually 2.

Comment: @Anand ahh that is true. Maybe a better answer is ceil(log2(number)) +  (0.0 == log2(number)).

Comment: The correct answer is  floor(log2(number)) +1